# security realm for tomcat only works for first request

Tags: jsp, servlets

i have set a Data source Realm security to a servlet app. but it works only for first request to the resource. for more requests i don't need any credentials.
why is it that way and how can i set tomcat to ask me credentials for every request to the specific resource , not just  for the first time.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your importing db should be static i.e. not only one session.
You can make a script for all details like following steps:
Create a script call createdb.sql and insert the following data:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tomcat_realm;
CREATE DATABASE tomcat_realm;
USE tomcat_realm;
CREATE TABLE tomcat_users (
    user_name varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    password varchar(250) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE tomcat_roles (
    user_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    role_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_name, role_name)
);
INSERT INTO tomcat_users (user_name, password) VALUES('someuser', '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99');
INSERT INTO tomcat_roles (user_name, role_name) VALUES ('someuser', 'authenticated');
COMMIT;
```

Go to mysql  and create data base and user:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
mysql> SOURCE ~/Documents/createdb.sql
mysql> use tomcat_realm;
mysql> show tables;
mysql> CREATE USER 'realm_access'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: i have no problem with database , my issue is tomcat does not ask credentials for every request to the url . it just works for first request and if i enter correct user & pass the server logs in and never ask for credentials in next requests from the same user. i need server ask credentials for every single request even if it is from a logged user . what should i do?  anyone help

Comment: I understood your point. As you told at first time it ask for credentials at first time and if user logged and again access the application no credentials asked. but it is expected behavior.

Comment: Because tomcat realm feature follow the following rule: When a user attempts to access a protected application for the first time, Tomcat will call the authenticate() method of this Realm. Thus, any changes you have made to the database directly will be immediately reflected.
Once a user has been authenticated, the user are cached within Tomcat for the duration of the user's login i.e. until the session times out or is invalidated or the user closes their browser, The cached user is not saved and restored across sessions serializations.